# How do I use matrix with image in gnuplot?

Tags: matrix

I have a **.dat** file in which there are **5000 rows** and **100 columns**. While I use **matrix with image** command in **gnuplot** 
*>plot "test.dat" matrix with image*
, a blank output occurs in gnuplot window. Whats wrong with this , anyone help me.

Comment: Should work. gnuplot version? Are you sure your data file is what you think it is?